# iOS - Correct way to ensure access to location coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, location-services

In my app I'm currently using a webview which I pass a URL containing the user's Lat/Lng. When the app starts, I `startUpdatingLocation`and listen for the `CLLocationManager` delegate method `didUpdateLocations` to initialise the webview using the coordinates provided in this method. There's a switch to ensure that the webview is only initialised once.

The problem is that this doesn't seem to be reliable -- sometimes when starting the app from close, this method is not triggered. It's strange, because most times it does work.

I've noticed that if I change location in the simulator, then it will trigger the method, but obviously this is a workaround and not a fix for the issue.

This leads me to think it's maybe because the location hasn't changed, but then how would I get that previous location coordinate?

I'm happy to post some code snippets if it'd help.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated -- thanks!

---

Additional code as requested:

Function to initialise location manager:

```
func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager!.delegate = self
        locationManager!.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
        print("Start updating location...")
}
```

Called in `loadView()`:

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        setupLocationManager()
    }

//... other code 
}
```

And while I'm posting code, here's the `didUpdateLocations()` method:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let coords = manager.location?.coordinate
    if !webViewStarted {
        webViewStarted = true
        startWebView(coords!)
    } else {
        updateUserLocation(coords!)
    }
}
```

`didChangeAuthorizationStatus` code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    var allow = false
    var message = ""
    switch status {
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
        message = "Restricted Access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
        message = "User denied access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
        message = "Status not determined"
    default:
        print("Allowed to location Access")
        allow = true
    }

    if (allow == true) {
        setupLocationManager()
    } else {
        message = "\(message) \r\n This app requires location services to use"
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Error getting location", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertView.addAction(cancel)
        self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you register for location updates?

Comment: @RafałSroka Just updated the main post -- thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using loadView instead of viewDidLoad? Seem like you would want to wait until your view and subviews had initialized before updating them. As in perhaps they have the location on hand and passing it to your webView, but your webView isn't loaded yet.

Comment: The location manager may already give you the coordinates as soon as you start it. Put some log in there. It always provides something at the beginning.

Comment: @beyowulf When learning about `WKWebView` I used [this tutorial](http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/15/wkwebview-and-javascript-in-ios-8-using-swift), and for some reason I also put the location setup stuff in there. I also have `viewDidLoad` which does a lot more, `loadView` currently only sets up the location manager and web view configuration.

Comment: @krafter, thanks for the suggestion, just did that, `locationManager.location` returns `nil` unfortunately.

Comment: They don't have a location manager. Do you see what I'm saying? loadView is called before your view and its subviews have been created. But you are kicking off activities that will talk to those subviews. Sometimes those actives might get performed faster than it takes to create the subviews. So they end up talking to nothing. Try moving setupLocationManager to viewDidLoad.

Comment: @beyowulf sorry, I just saw your edit. As @krafter suggested, I've been logging the `locationManager.location` at the end of the the `setupLocationManager` function and it's `nil`, even after moving it to `viewDidLoad`. I have noticed it is running twice though, once on view load and once of the `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` method, which shouldn't be called (unless it auto runs? I'm not changing the status.).

Comment: Log it out in **locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])**! That would make it clear.

Comment: @krafter I do that too, but the root of the issue here is that this method isn't being triggered at all, so nothing prints.

Comment: I feel like I should add that this problem rarely occurs, but when it does I can fix it by going to Debug > Location > Apple, then switching back to my custom location and restarting the app. Today I didn't do that because I need to fix the cause of it (it is also sometimes happening on devices). Thanks for all the input so far!

Comment: Where do you declare locationManager and what does that look like? What happens when you change locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() to locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()? What happens when you put a print statement in func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])? What does didChangeAuthorizationStatus look like?

Comment: @beyowulf Just updated the main post with `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` status code. Will look into your other suggestions once I can replicate the issue again. Thanks so much for your input so far!

Comment: Regarding didChangeAuthorizationStatus, I'd look at http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/ to see when and how often it's called.